# Load 3D model in Unity using Resource folder and Mysql

Tags: mysql, unity-game-engine, model

I want to load 3D model using Resource folder. I created an sql database to store the address. In this case I stored the file "deer-3ds" in folder "Models" and also save these information in a table named "modeladdress" in sql.
So please help me to correct my code. I know that it's 100% wrong but I dont know how to fix it. Thank you.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System;
using System.Data;
using Mono.Data.Sqlite;


public class addobject : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //GameObject deer=Instantiate(Resources.Load("deer-3d.bak",typeof(GameObject)))as GameObject;
//      GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Models/deer-3ds", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
        string conn = "URI=file:" + Application.dataPath + "/modeladdress.s3db"; //Path to database.
        IDbConnection dbconn;
        dbconn = (IDbConnection) new SqliteConnection(conn);
        dbconn.Open(); //Open connection to the database.
        IDbCommand dbcmd = dbconn.CreateCommand();
        string sqlQuery = "SELECT ordinary,foldername, filename " + "FROM modeladdress";
        dbcmd.CommandText = sqlQuery;
        IDataReader reader = dbcmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read ()) {
            int ordinary = reader.GetInt32 (0);
            string foldername = reader.GetString (1);
            string filename = reader.GetString (2);
            string path = foldername + "/" + filename;

            //Debug.Log( "value= "+value+"  name ="+name+"  random ="+  rand);
            GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load(path, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
            instance.SetActive (true);
        }

        reader.Close();
        reader = null;
        dbcmd.Dispose();
        dbcmd = null;
        dbconn.Close();
        dbconn = null;


    }


    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
//      GameObject instance = Instantiate(Resources.Load("Models/deer-3ds", typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
//      instance.SetActive (true);


    }
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is happening that's "wrong"?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are using SQLite at your database management system, not MySQL. Second, the way you have written your query,

> string sqlQuery = "SELECT ordinary,foldername, filename " + "FROM modeladdress";

Will return the `ordinary`, `foldername`, and `filename` for **every** model. You need to use a `WHERE` clause to specify precisely which model you want to use. Thus, you need some way to know which model you want to query from the database before you actually execute the query, and in that case, why even query a database? You're going to have to store some unique identifier anyway so a database solves nothing.

Now concerning the actual code you have written, it appears to be correct (i.e. it *should* be returning what you want). The problem must be that either your table is empty, your values that are returned are incorrect, or that the object is being instantiated in an incorrect location and thus you are thinking it's not working. If you want a more concrete answer you'll have to comment on this answer with the specific problem you are facing (i.e. what specifically is "wrong"?).